# examine if values across several columns equal to any element in a list using R

Tags: r

My dataset has several diagnose columns: diag1, diag2, diag3,...diagn. I would like to identify conditions using all the diagnosis fields. The conditions are also a list, which is:

`cond_list <- c ("A09", "B10", "C25", "D98")`

In other words, if any field, from `diag1` to `diagn`, has values which meet any element in the `cond_list`, the condition will be coded as 1.

At this point, my code reads like this (just going to simplify but n is more than 5 and condition list is more than 4 conditions):

```
col <- c("diag1", "diag2", "diag3", "diag4", "diag5")  
data$condition <- ((rowSums(data[, col] == "A09"|data[, col] == "B10"|data[, col] == "C25" == data[, col] == "D98", na.rm=T) > 0) * 1)
```

Wondering if there is a better way so I do not have to type all the conditions in `cond_list`? I actually have more than 100 or so.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach:

You can convert your diagnosis dataset to long, and check each diagnosis to see if in your condition list. Then sum up the conditions by each individual.

```
dx_df <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1,2,3),
  diag_1 = c("A09", "J32", "S45"),
  diag_2 = c("B10", "D98", "M31"),
  diag_3 = c("C25", "C25", "Q02")
)

cond_list <- c("A09", "B10", "C25", "D98")

library(tidyverse)

dx_df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -ID, names_to = c(".value", "number"), names_sep = "_") %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(condition = if_else(diag %in% cond_list, 1, 0)) %>%
  summarise(total = sum(condition)) %>%
  right_join(dx_df)

# A tibble: 3 x 5
     ID total diag_1 diag_2 diag_3
  <dbl> <dbl> <fct>  <fct>  <fct> 
1     1     3 A09    B10    C25   
2     2     2 J32    D98    C25   
3     3     0 S45    M31    Q02
```

As an aside, if you want to filter your dataframe based on rows having at least one diagnosis contained within your condition list, you could do the following (also using `tidyverse`):

```
dx_df %>% 
  filter_at(vars(starts_with("diag")), any_vars(. %in% cond_list))

  ID diag_1 diag_2 diag_3
1  1    A09    B10    C25
2  2    J32    D98    C25
```

Comment: Thank you! How can I save this "total" column as a new variable column to dx_df?

Comment: you could add `right_join(dx_df)` at end of pipe (see edited answer)

Comment: which join to which? I tried "total" -- not working though. also tried but failed:dx_df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -ID, names_to = c(".value", "number"), names_sep = "_") %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(condition = if_else(diag %in% cond_list, 1, 0)) %>%
  summarise(total = sum(condition), right_join(dx_df))

Comment: Sorry see answer above - needs to be separate by pipe %>%

Answer (score 0):

You can use `%in%` to check if the values of one vector are in another vector. Then to check if at least one element is present we can use `any` function.

For example:

```
data$condition <- apply(data, 1, function(x) any(x %in% cond_list))
```